# Spring WebFlux Mono.switchIfEmpty is getting called even if data present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to Spring webflux. Need to understand why Mono.switchIfEmpty operator is getting called even if data is not empty.

**Sample Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mono.just("test1")
            .flatMap(val -> {
                System.out.println("test2");
                return Mono.just("test2");
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(method1())
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

private static Mono<String> method1() {
    System.out.println("test3");
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

**Output**

test3
test2
test2

Answer (score 6):

With project reactor (and in reactive programming in general, to some extent), things happen in two stages:

1. Setting up the reactive pipeline
2. The actual execution of that pipeline as soon as a `Subscriber` subscribes to it

In your case, calling `method1` executes that method and your `System.out.println` is executed as expected.

If you want to see more in line with the pipeline execution, you could try:

```
private static Mono<String> method1() {
    return Mono.defer(() -> {
        System.out.println("test3");            
        return Mono.empty()
    });
}
```

The `Mono.defer` operator will defer that operation until the pipeline is subscribed to.

There are better ways to achieve that though:

- you could use one of the many `DoOnXYZ` operators, which are meant for side-effect operations like that
- you could use the `log()` operator to get a better idea of what's happening here (subscription, backpressure, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Brian. Now its clear to me, I have tried and working as expected.